# Apparently random purple 'tearing' on iPhone 5 camera under iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I'm using AVFoundation to set up and display a custom camera interface. I've used a lot of code from Apple's AVCam sample code project. It works mostly but every now and then the camera display 'tears', with parts of the screen displaying a bright purple.

I have no idea why this could be happening. It seems to be completely random (usually happens when I move the camera around though). Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Why is there a vote to close this? It seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me. Reasoning?

Comment: This is obviously a hardware issue and not a software issue. So I'm assuming that's why (although I wasn't the one that did downvote or voted to close)

Comment: @Lefteris I doubt it's a hardware issue. The camera works fine with the default iPhone camera app. The problems only occurs in the app I had built.

Comment: Are you only seeing this on iOS 7 or only on a specific piece of hardware? I've had reports of something similar on iPhone 5 with iOS 7 when pulling in from AV Foundation: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1236 . It's possible this is a framework bug (I know that there was a somewhat similar glitch in iOS 5 in AV Foundation). It might be worth filing a bug report on, if the specific cases that trigger this can be identified.

Comment: @BradLarson It's happening on an iPhone 5 running iOS 7. That issue on GitHub sounds identical to what I'm experiencing. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue for iPhone 5 and iOS 7. I have experienced it quite a few times (on multiple iPhone 5 models) even with native Camera.app.

When asking questions that might relate to HW issues you'd better state your device and OS version because it can help us help you.

Try running your code on another device and if that helps I'd suggest you visit nearest Apple Store to claim this problem.